# WooCommerce My Account Page from page.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created `my-account.php` inside woocommece folder in my custom theme.
But, when I want to display what is inside my-account.php file, My Account page take template from `page.php`. What a drag coherent content...

My custom theme support WC, in settings all is (at least it should) adjusted properly.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just brainstorming late at night... - in your page settings (admin > pages > {page} ) have you got it a specific page selected in the drop down as another template file? Have you placed the replacement file in the exact required location as per wordpress/woocommerce requirements for child template files eg: child-theme/woocommerce/my-account/{filename}.php ? Additional reading: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @Aliqua, I follow your path and again same.

Comment: I just thought: the "my-account" page usually has the my account shortcode in it... perhaps you could try make changes to/add to your child page templates the dashboard.php instead?